# Querying AD from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2012, active-directory

I've read tons of questions and answers about my error but none of them helped me ( from PINAL website, microsoft links and everything ). questions from 9 years ago to today.

I created a Linked server with proper user/pass to read info from our AD.

but it doesn't matter what user I use ( we tried everything, even with the most powerfull user we have in the network that can make it rain if it wants ) and I still get the same error:

```
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
The OLE DB provider "ADsDSOObject" for linked server "ADSI" reported an error. The provider indicates that the user did not have the permission to perform the operation.
```

i tried to run SSMS with the user with no success. I set the secutiry tab to run with the specific user that can read the AD.

```
these are the queries i'm trying :
SELECT top 100 * FROM OpenQuery (
ADSI, 'SELECT displayname FROM 
''LDAP://myDomain.local/OU=Usuarios'''
) 


SELECT TOP 100 * FROM OPENQUERY
(ADSI,'SELECT displayname FROM 
''LDAP://myDomain.local/OU=USUARIOS,DC=MyDomain,DC=LOCAL'''
)

SELECT * FROM OpenQuery (
ADSI,
'SELECT *
FROM ''LDAP://myDomain.local/DC=MyDomain,DC=local''
WHERE objectClass = ''User''
')
```

I opened management studio with this powerfull user and it still doesnt work.  what can be the error here?

I'm querying the AD server remotely from my machine from SSMS.

Comment: What information are you trying to capture from AD? This is something generally better done from an application, rather than the database. Adding context to the information you're trying to get from AD might lead to better answers.

Comment: I would like to query users info, like emails, names and etc to create a proper report of it.

Comment: Sorry but why is the question being downvoted? Ive seen that this is used a lot, as I found tons of websites with info about it, but unfortunatelly none of them had the fix to my problem.

Comment: Is there any reason SQL has to talk to the AD directly rather than say an overnight batch job running in a list into a table? This whole pattern is an odd one for me.

Comment: My boss asked me if it was possible , so we can filter areas, etc etc and I said i've heard of it, so I'm trying to learn more about this possibility. and whats killing me is that the linked server is ok, connection was succesfully but I'm receiving this permission error even using the most powerfull login we have.

Comment: For reporting purposes, I'd generally recommend writing an ETL process (in Powershell, SSIS, Python, whatever you like) to query AD & load to the database. Then your report can just report on the data in the database. Is that an option? Or is there a business requirement that makes "last night's" or "this morning's AD data too stale for the report?

Comment: SQL Server really not the place for this. But the answer to your problem is that the **SQL Server service account** needs read permissions, not the executing user.

Comment: Hey thanks @Charlieface. it is place for this, and we tried that. maximum permission for sql service account too.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off and find it easier to query **Active Directory** with a **CLR stored procedure** or **CLR function**. See [this walkthrough](https://pawlowski.cz/2011/04/13/querying-active-directory-sql-server-clr/) on how to do so, as this is how I've done it in the past. Also someone else [made one](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1095447/Active-Directory-Query-using-CLR-Stored-Procedure) already you can look into (but be careful installing CLR assemblies from outside sources).

Comment: thanks for the info JD. but i think this is not going to solve the problem, as I can see it creates the same final query as i'm using above. obviously fixing the 1000 rows but this is another story  and I can fix this later.

Comment: @RacerSQL It'll help you debug the problem if it actually is a security issue since CLR is typically coded in Visual Studio. Otherwise it may side-step the problem as a workaround if it's not a true security issue. Definitely worth considering.